# POVRay referencing object rotation values

Tags: object, reference, rotation, povray

How can I reference an object in POVRay? I mean I want to rotate another object on axis X by another object's rotation value of its Z axis.

I am thinking about someting like this (this of course does not work, just to show you what I mean):

```
// lets say before I #declared two objects named ObjA & ObjB
Object {
    ObjA
    rotate <ObjB.rotation.z, 0, 0>
}
```

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the objects synchronized through a variable, e.g.:

```
#declare Rotation = <5, 3, 4>;

Object  {
    ObjB
    rotate Rotation
}

Object  {
    ObjA
    rotate <Rotation.x, 0, 0>
}
```

Note that if you change (re-declare) Rotation later, you will need to update the objects' rotation manually by using the `vrotate()` built-in function.